# Adobe Acrobat 9.0 not working any longer?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

Before installing it on my 64bit Windows 7 PC, it worked on my XP platform for years. That was in June and it'd been working fine on the new Windows 7 platform ever since. Until today. I uninstalled it and re-installed it and it doesn't turn on. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We still use Acrobat Standard *8* with Windows 7 on a few machines at work.

But to do this, right after we install it, we have to run about 15-20 updates to get it up to version 8.3.1 before it'll actually run on 7.

Check out Adobe's site to get the updates for your version.  [Here's the current direct link.](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=1&platform=Windows)

Acrobat 9's last version seems to be 9.5.5.

Tip: You don't have to restart between each update (even if it says you do).

Comment: I'm downloading it as I write this. Let me try it once it's done and get back to u. Thanks a bunch even if it doesn't do the trick!!

Comment: There was an error message (didn't copy it down) and I thought about it and decided to download the earliest update which I'm trying now.

Comment: Wellllll....it took me forever to do that,but I installed every one of them little upgrades in their little sequence; I didn't restart the PC when it told me to (only after all of 'em were installed) and then I restarted it. Guess what? It still doesn't work!

Comment: Will Adobe provide me with an answer?

Comment: Crappy.  Perhaps edit your question and explain what you did and what "doesn't work" about it.  Like, what happens when you try? Anything in the Event Logs?  Have you tried fully uninstalling and reinstalling it?  You also may want to check Adobe's user forums, and/or bite the bullet and call them.  Then come back and update with what you discovered.  Note: The lack of doing that stuff in advance is what probably garnered you all those down-votes.

Comment: "Doesn' work" mean? It means when you try clicking on the desktop icon 'nothing happens'. What are the 'Event Logs' in your mention? I had already uninstalled and re-installed the blessed thing.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/open-event-viewer